# Can I set the width of a table cell element via CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, dimensions

I need to add ellipsis to table cells whose contents exceed a certain threshold value.

Say I have this:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">Fooooooooooooooooooooo</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">b</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">c</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">d</a></td>
</tr>
```

Currently I'm setting this in CSS:

```
table tr td a,
table tr th a {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ th,
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ td {
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

but it does not work = table cells are not limited to 25% of available width.

**Question:**
Is it possible to set a table cell width in CSS? Or can I only target the content of a table cell?

Comment: Basically you would have to change the default `display: table-cell` to something else, but that could have far-reaching consequences.

Comment: mh. nice idea, but not really an option. thx

Comment: i don't believe there is any other CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a table's cell assumes the defined css width, but it will grow along to fit its inline/block content, ignoring the defined rule.

A possible solution is to remove the anchor from the normal flow, setting it as `position: absolute;` and making it full width. This would prevent the cell from expanding, and would limit the anchor to  `100%` of the available cell's width.

*Remember to set the table cell as `position: relative` for it to act as a container*

*Also remember to set the table's width, otherwise `25%` will mean nothing*

```css
table tr td a,
table tr th a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
    width: 200px;
}

table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ th,
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ td {
  max-width: 25%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">Fooooooooooooooooooooo</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">b</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">c</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">d</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues involved. First, the `table` element has no width assigned to it. Second, the default is automatic table layout where column widths get adjusted according to requirements of the content; you can override this by setting `table-layout` to `fixed`. Third, the `a` element has no width constraint set on it; to fix this, set a width on it and make it formatted as a block element (since by default it is an inline element and the `width` property is ignored). Example:

```css
table {
  width: 10em;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
table tr td a,
table tr th a {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr th:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ th,
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr td:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ td {
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table border>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">Fooooooooooooooooooooo</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">b</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">c</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">d</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```